# How to update the View using an init method in the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, initialization, mvvm-light

I'm new in WPF and MVVM (I'm using MvvmLight Toolkit) so the way I'm coding is maybe wrong.

The scenario is the following:

I would like to perform initialisation stuff every time i switch views.
So I have created a new `InitViewModelBase` which inherits `ViewModel`

```
Public MustInherit Class InitViewModelBase
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    ...

    Public MustOverride Sub Init()

End Class
```

I call this `Init` method when switching view

```
Private _currentViewModel As InitViewModel
Public Property CurrentViewModel() As InitViewModel
    Get
        Return _currentViewModel
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As InitViewModel)
        If _currentViewModel IsNot value Then
            _currentViewModel = value
            _currentViewModel.Init
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Now I would like to update for example the content of a Label in the `Init` method

```
Private _test As String
Public Property Test() As String = "TEST"
    Get
        Return _test
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _test = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Test")
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Sub Init()
    Test = "UPDATE"
End Sub

<Label Content="{Binding Test}"/>
```

**Why is my label content never updated when i set a new value in my Init method ?**

If I set a new value in the constructor it works great.

Comment: Are you setting the datacontext correctly? Use a tool like snoop and see if the binding is fine and that you are not getting any errors

Comment: Yes, the label content is well displayed if I set a default value.